# How to make a Windows 7 live cd

Tags: windows-7, livecd

Do you have any idea on how to create a live cd for windows 7?
I tried Bart pe but I think its only for Windows xp. And when I tried it to create a live cd for xp. And booted the iso image created by bart pe. It doesnt look xp at all, the GUI does not look like xp and it has only limited task that you can run.

Answer (score 6):

I used [WinBuilder](http://winbuilder.net/) to create a live, bootable Win 7 USB drive.

- basically scripts Microsoft's WAIK PETools mentioned in another post. It's just a matter of selecting the right project that has already been scripted.
- has a GUI front-end to customize various settings (including the option to use the native Windows 7 explorer shell, which was not the default when I used it)
- optionally pre-install software like web browsers and anti-virus

There is very active discussion on the [Win7RescuePE forums](http://www.boot-land.net/forums/index.php?showforum=91), including [detailed instructions](http://psc.boot-land.net/Creating%20Win7RescuePE.doc) in MS Word format with screen shots.

---

**update:** it seems the host of the WinBuilder project file for Win7RescuePE is currently not available. [Recent messages](http://www.boot-land.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=8774&st=1130) in the forum have links to [alternate download links](http://homes32.winbuilder.net/projects/Win7RescuePE_Upload.zip):

> QUOTE (chameleon215 @ May 22 2010,
>   07:19 PM)
>
> > Haven't been able to download any
> >     updates for Win7RescuePE for quite
> >     sometime, neither
> >     rescue.w07.net/Projects or
> >     joshua.winbuilder.net/Projects links
> >     are working. Can someone please let us
> >     know what the new address is?
>
> I have uploaded a untouched copy of
>   psc's Win7RescuePE_Upload.zip
>
> you can get it here.
>
> [http://homes32.winbuilder.net/projects/Win...uePE_Upload.zip](http://homes32.winbuilder.net/projects/Win7RescuePE_Upload.zip)

Comment: I tried winBuilder but it needs to download some files after executing. And it seems that the sites that host those files doesn't have those files anymore. I thought so because it downloads a 384 kb file too long

Comment: @Nrew: try the alternate download links I added.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Windows live cd can be done quite easily by using WAIK provided by Microsoft

http://www.ditii.com/2009/06/06/windows-7-bootable-cd-using-waik/

```
CD "C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools" 
CALL copype.cmd x86 c:\winpe_x86copy c:\winpe_x86\winpe.wim c:\winpe_x86\ISO\sources\boot.wim 
copy "C:\program files\Windows AIK\Tools\x86\imagex.exe" C:\winpe_x86\iso\ 
oscdimg -n -bC:\winpe_x86\etfsboot.com C:\winpe_x86\ISO C:\winpe_x86\winpe_x86.iso
rem To remove the "Press any key to boot from CD" prompt during boot, 
rem remove the bootfix.bin file from the \boot folder within your mounted image. pause
```

Comment: The dl link in the site is broken

Comment: It's free from Microsoft 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c7d4bc6d-15f3-4284-9123-679830d629f2&displaylang=en